# WebApi service call authentication with WS-Federation and SAML

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, adal, ws-federation

I'm trying to integrate WSFederation into my asp.net web api. I have 2 azure hosted app services one is for webapp and one webApi. Users can access WebApi from WebApp or can make direct calls from the browser.

I looked at azure samples https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect and https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation

I am unable to integrate both the samples to have what I need i.e. use WSFederation for web application and webApi.

P.S. I'm getting back SAML token from IdP and we are not using ADFS but Ping.

Comment: What is the error you are getting back?

Comment: Both provided samples uses different sign-in protocol. I am not sure about the integration procedure. How can I make a call from WebApp which uses WS-Federation with SAML to WebApi controller? In the provided sample WebApi uses OpenId with JWT. Any pointers or sample implementation is highly appreciated.